# POST http://localhost:1337/openai/text 505 (HTTP Version Not Supported)

Tags: http-status-code-429, http-status-code-505

I am creating a chat with AI GPT, but I'm getting an error 505 (HTTP Version Not Supported) when trying to use the following code:

```js
router.post("/text", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { text, activeChatId } = req.body;
    console.log("req.body", req.body);

    const response = await openai.createCompletion({ // this line seems to be the cause of the problem
      model: "text-davinci-003",
      prompt: text,
      temperature: 0.5,
      max_tokens: 2048,
      top_p: 1,
      frequency_penalty: 0.5,
      presence_penalty: 0,
    });

    await axios.post(
      `https://api.chatengine.io/chats/${activeChatId}/messages/`,
      { text: response.data.choices[0].text },
      {
        headers: {
          "Project-ID": process.env.PROJECT_ID,
          "User-Name": process.env.BOT_USER_NAME,
          "User-Secret": process.env.BOT_USER_SECRET,
        },
      }
    );

    res.status(200).json({ text: response.data.choices[0].text });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(505).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

Upon checking, `req.body` seems to be receiving data, but `response.data` is not. In the console, the headers show "505 HTTP Version Not Supported," while the response shows `{"error":"Request failed with status code 429"}`. I am inexperienced in programming and would appreciate help solving this issue.

Here is a screenshot of the error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlMJB.png